# onPageFinished method is called BEFORE the website finishes loading?

Tags: android, webview

It seems that I made some inaccuracies or I missed something regarding `public class myWebViewClient` class and `public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)`. Initially and in the beginning I tried to launch www.yahoo.com and after it finishes loading I fire a toast from inside the `public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` as indication to me the loading of the www.yahoo.com is finished, and up to here every thing is fine. Inside my RelativeLayout I have a button and edittext and my webview is layedout-above them. The purpose of having an edittext is to enable the user to enter their webite and by clicking on go-button, the entered website should be launched and I expect to see the toast I have inside `public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` is fired again after the new website finishes loading. But what happens is, once the user enters a new website in the edittext field and immediately after they press go_button the toast fires before even the website is loaded and it fires once again after the same web site is finished loading. Actually, I expect the toast to be fired only after every website finishes loading, but what is happening with me is not like that. Please provide me with suggestions to prevent occurring such problem.

JavaCode:

```
OnClickListener btnGoListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        webView00.loadUrl(etUrl.getText().toString());
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_page00);

    webView00 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView00);
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_btn);
    etUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url_edittext);

    webView00.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView00.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    webView00.setWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient());

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(btnGoListener);
    webView00.loadUrl("http://google.com");
}

public class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

}

public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {        
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                       .show();
        }
    };
```

Comment: What URLs are passed in to `onPageFinished` when you see each of the calls?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have not tried the Chrome client yet, so have commented that one out, perhaps you can change seamlessly between them.

Nevertheless, I would think something like this should work:

```
OnClickListener btnGoListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        webView00.loadUrl(etUrl.getText().toString());
        webView00.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading Finished 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
            }
        });
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_page00);

    webView00 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView00);
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_btn);
    etUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url_edittext);

    webView00.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(btnGoListener);
    webView00.loadUrl("http://google.com");

    //webView00.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    //webView00.setWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient());
    webView00.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading Finished 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you.please advice concerning the following: 1)could webChromeClient implies a solution for my question?how? 2)should I declare onPageFinished callbacks for each website I want to load?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer, have been afk. 1) have no experience with webChromeClient but noticed that it has some more callbacks that might be helpful 2) With the current answer that is what happens, I would think that you could inspect the url string to implement different behavior for each site, if that is what you aim to do.

Comment: I don't see much logical difference in the code marked as answer and the code initially posted. Can you please point out what was the difference that made it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Been a while since I posted this. But as I recall, calling `setWebViewClient` again in onClick was needed to determine when loading of a new url was completed.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation :

```
When onPageFinished() is called, the rendering picture may not be updated yet. 
To get the notification for the new Picture, use onNewPicture(WebView, Picture).
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView), java.lang.String)

I suggest that you implement method `onProgressChanged` from WebChromeClient.

Documentation :

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onProgressChanged(android.webkit.WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onProgressChanged%28android.webkit.WebView), int)

Comment: Suggested solution doesn't work either. Have tried, only top third of an image got loaded, rest was blank.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed `onPageFinished` is sometimes called multiple times if the webview re-rendered a page that was already loaded.  On the reload, the webview would first render `about:blank` and calls `onPageFinished` before loading the actual webpage and calling `onPageFinished` again. The sequence is:

1. load `www.google.com`
2. `onPageFinished` is called
3. load 'www.google.com' again
4. `onPageFinished` is called.  The URL is `about:blank`
5. `onPageFinished` is called.  The URL is `www.google.com`

To get around this issue in step 4, you can check that the `url` parameter passed to `onPageFinished` is the one you care about:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
    
        webView00.loadUrl(myWebPage);
    }

    
    public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {        
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, URL);
            if(url == myWebPage) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                           .show();
            }
        };
```