# How to handle a button pressed inside the webChromeClient callbacks?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webclient, webchromeclient

How to make the `webChromeClient()`calss's callbacks handles and listen to a button?
The problem I have is that, I have a `button` and an`edittext` field, both of them are in a `RelativeLayout` and the `webView` is layed-out above them so I can avoid mixing the contents of the displayed webpage with both of the `button`and `edittext`. The purpose of having an `edittext` field is to allow the user to enter a webpage name. And the purpose of having a `button` is to launch the webpage the user have entered. I also use `webClientView` class and a toast inside the callback `onPageFinished` to notify me whenever the webpage finishes loading. But whenever I press the `button` to launch the a webpage specified in the `edittext` field, the callback `onPageFinish` is always called even BEFORE the webpage finishes loading. For an example, if I specified a website address in the `edittext` and pressed the `button` repeatedly, I will get the toast output as much as the number of pressings on the `button`. Please refer to my question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155432/onpagefinished-method-is-called-before-the-website-finishes-loading/23155712?noredirect=1#23155712) which is almost regarding the same issue. despite it solved my problem partially, when I was coding the demands of the App, I then realized that answers on my question I referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155432/onpagefinished-method-is-called-before-the-website-finishes-loading/23155712?noredirect=1#23155712)  are seamed and or not sufficient. Is there any way to solve that issue using the `webChromeView` class? and how?

JavaCode:

```
OnClickListener btnGoListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        webView00.loadUrl(etUrl.getText().toString());
        webView00.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading Finished 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
            }
        });
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_page00);

    webView00 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView00);
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_btn);
    etUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url_edittext);

    webView00.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView00.setWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient());

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(btnGoListener);
    webView00.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    webView00.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading Finished 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
        }
    });

}

public class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting a new webviewclient every time the button is clicked? Just do it once.

Comment: because I got this problem in the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155432/onpagefinished-method-is-called-before-the-website-finishes-loading